# IndexOutOfBoundsException using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, combobox

I have a option for the user to pick a Month. I set a listener `ItemListener` for my ComboBox which contains list of Months. I have a set condition where if the user pick **"February"** list of days will only up to 29 else **"April","June"** and so on will have 30 days on my ComboBox. But when I choose **"February"** it works fine but when I select another month I get an error.

`IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 30, Size: 29`

I know this error occur because the another month has a Index of 30. I'm little bit confuse should I remove the content of ArrayList or the ComboBox? Any help how can I eliminate this?

```
private ItemHandler handler = new ItemHandler();

ArrayList<String> daysList = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] daysObj = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
        "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"};
 DefaultComboBoxModel daysModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(daysObj);

public AddEmployee() 
{
  setMonths();
  setDays();
  cbMonths.addItemListener(handler);
}

private void setDays()
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < daysObj.length; i++)
    {
        daysList.add(daysObj[i]);
    }

    cbDays.setModel((ComboBoxModel)daysModel);   
}

private class ItemHandler implements ItemListener
{
    int removeDays[] = {29,30};//array
    int remove[] = {30};
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getSource() == cbMonths)//Check where combobox occured.
        {
            if(cbMonths.getSelectedItem().equals("February"))
            {
                for(int i = removeDays.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    daysList.remove(removeDays[i]);//Remove given array from ArrayList using removeDays[]
                    System.out.println("NEW ELEMENT: "+daysList);
                }

                for(String s : daysList)//Update ArrayList
                {
                    cbDays.addItem(s);
                    System.out.println("NEW LIST OF ARRAY: "+s);
                }

            }
            else if(cbMonths.getSelectedItem().equals("April") || cbMonths.getSelectedItem().equals("June") || 
                    cbMonths.getSelectedItem().equals("September") || cbMonths.getSelectedItem().equals("November"))
            {
                for(int i = remove.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    daysList.remove(remove[i]);
                    System.out.println(daysList);
                }

                for(String a : daysList)//Update ArrayList
                {
                    cbDays.addItem(a);
                    System.out.println("NEW LIST OF ARRAY: "+a);
                }

            }
      }
}
```

I tried a method `removeAllItems()` but it look likes it doesn't work. `cbDays.removeAllItems();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing complex calculations each time a user chooses another month (which is hard to read and error prone), better initialize some static models which cover all cases. Your StateChaged handler then only has to pick the correct model. Following example is based on the new fancy java 8 datetime API:

```
private static String[] initDays( int number )
{
    String[] result = new String[ number];

    for ( int i = 0; i < result.length; i++ )
    {
        result[i] = "" + ( i+1);
    }

    return result;
}

private static final String[] days28 = initDays( 28);
private static final String[] days29 = initDays( 29);
private static final String[] days30 = initDays( 30);
private static final String[] days31 = initDays( 31);

private static final ComboBoxModel<String> model28 = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(days28);
private static final ComboBoxModel<String> model29 = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(days29);
private static final ComboBoxModel<String> model30 = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(days30);
private static final ComboBoxModel<String> model31 = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(days31);

private static final Set<Month> month30 = EnumSet.of(
         Month.FEBRUARY,
         Month.APRIL,
         Month.JUNE,
         Month.SEPTEMBER,
         Month.NOVEMBER
     );
private static final Set<Month> month31 = EnumSet.of(
         Month.JANUARY,
         Month.MARCH,
         Month.MAY,
         Month.JULY,
         Month.AUGUST,
         Month.OCTOBER,
         Month.DECEMBER
     );
private JComboBox<String> cbMonths = new JComboBox<>();
private JComboBox<String> cbDays = new JComboBox<>();

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == cbMonths)//Check where combobox occured.
    {
        if(cbMonths.getSelectedItem().equals("February"))
        {
            Month selectedMonth = Month.valueOf( cbMonths.getItemAt( cbMonths.getSelectedIndex() ) );

            if ( month31.contains( selectedMonth ) )
            {
                cbDays.setModel( model31 );
            }
            else if ( month30.contains( selectedMonth ) )
            {
                cbDays.setModel( model30 );
            }
            else
            {
                if ( Year.isLeap( Instant.now().getLong( ChronoField.YEAR ) ) )
                {
                    cbDays.setModel( model29 );
                }
                else
                {
                    cbDays.setModel( model28 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A further enhancement could be to use a cbMonth which is directly typed by the Month enum, and provide a cell renderer which displays the month in the locale of the user.

Comment: Hi! @Heri I'm still analyzing your code and tried it already. I used GUI Builder on this project. Should I still call the `private JComboBox<String> cbMonths = new JComboBox<>();`? Because cbMonths and cbDays is already define :D. Also I'm little bit confuse calling `initDays()` in the constructor. It should be concatenated with object of the class right? `myObject.initDays();`?

Comment: The lines where I initialize the cbMonths and cbDays were only used in my eclipse in order to compile (and I have copied it in a whole to here). If you already have initialized instances just use these.

Comment: initDays is not called in the constructor. It is static and is called only once: when the class is loaded by the classloader of JVM.

Comment: Since it's already define in my GUI I commented out the `private JComboBox<String> cbMonths = new JComboBox<>();` because it gives me a error and tried run your code but it doesn't change the days when I chose "February".

Comment: Sorry, there is bug in my month30 Set: remove there the FEBRUARY element.

Comment: Of course you must also adapt the leap year calculation to your needs. My example uses the current year. You maybe have a year combo box: just use the value from there.

Comment: I already remove the FEBRUARY element. It still nothing happened.

Comment: Nice.. But I'm compatible with your code that you given especially using the java 8 date time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124741/discussion-between-heri-and-john-francis).

Answer (score 0):

After initialization via `setDays()` `daysList` contains 31 elements. When `February` is selected, two elements with the index `29` and `30` are removed:

```
    daysList.remove(removeDays[i])
```

`daysList` is now having `29` elements. When another month is selected, one element with index `30` is removed

```
    daysList.remove(remove[i]);
```

But `dayslist` only has 29 elements, so an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.

Therefore one solution might be to re-initialize `daysList` everytime `itemStateChanged` is triggered.